# Unexpected response code 400 in YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar demo app

Tags: android-youtube-api

I'm getting these errors after downloading and running the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar demo app

[logs from IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU8Hg.png)

> E/Volley: [1054] axb.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=AIzaSyCjc_pVEDi4qsv5MtC2dMXzpIaDoRFLsxw&id=wKJ9KzGQq0w&t=xUuh7B2jySQ3
>
> E/Volley: [1043] axb.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/next?key=AIzaSyCjc_pVEDi4qsv5MtC2dMXzpIaDoRFLsxw&asig=BlUgXBq_ty3hax4TufEh1Njvq5MjlzJYhP2O1m2KUQM

In some devices all works fine, but in some of them I'm getting these errors and seeing such result [error screen in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPJ3Y.png)